# How to scale a few features of specific columns within pandas dataframe while preserving other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing it this way
1- dropping columns from the main dataframe which doesn't need feature scaling
2- now obtained dataframe only has columns that require feature scaling
3- concatenate the dropped out columns with the scaled columns to get the final dataframe

but

I want to do it without dropping any columns. buy using a command that will scale first 14 columns but the others are preserved in the dataframe I get as an output

Answer (score 1):

Look in to [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). Setting the axis parameter to 1 will apply a function along columns. You can put a filter in that function to only include the columns you want to scale.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

def scaling_function(x, col_to_scale):
    for col in x.index:
        if col in col_to_scale:
            #your scaling operation here
            x[col] = x[col] * 2
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9, 2]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
col_to_scale = ['A', 'B']
scaled_df = df.apply(lambda x: scaling_function(x, col_to_scale), axis=1)
```

Will double the values in column A & B while leaving C as is.